# How to create an action which closes all popovers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

How to create an action which closes all popovers? For example I click one of the popovers and it opens as well . Then I click another popover and it opens as well, but previous popover closes. This action have to works for all popovers.

```
<ul>            
<li>                      
<a class="alerts-menu" data-toggle="popover" data placement="bottom">Notifications</a>
<div id="alerts-popover-content" style="display:none">FIRST CONTENT</div>
</li>

<li>                      
<a class="tasks-menu" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Tasks</a>                   
<div id="tasks_popover_content" style="display:none">SECOND CONTENT</div>
</li>

</ul>



    $(function(){

        $('[data-toggle=popover].alerts-menu').popover({ 
            html : true, 
            content: function() {
              return $('#alerts-popover-content').html();
            }
        }); 

        $('[data-toggle=popover].tasks-menu').popover({ 
            html : true, 
            content: function() {
              return $('#tasks_popover_content').html();
            }
        });
    });
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!!! =) I DID IT!!
I've never  code js before :D
Here is code**

```
$(function () { 
$("[data-toggle=popover]").click(function() {
 var me = this;
 $("[data-toggle=popover] + .popover").each(function() {
  if (me != this)
   $(this).hide();
 });
})  });
```

**I hope this will be helpful for you**

Comment: IMO, if you only want one popover to be open at any time, you'd need to store the "last open popover" somewhere and close it (e.g. `close if last_popover is not null`) when a new popover is shown. If you want *all* to be closed, you'd need to iterate through them. either way, you need to amend the default `popover()` with your own code.

Comment: You are right! I want this " 'last open popover' somewhere and close it (e.g. close if last_popover is not null) when a new popover is shown". well .. how to make this code? =)

Comment: My first feeling would be to rewrite the `popover.js`. it's not that big.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`$('[data-toggle=popover]').hide()`

Comment: Thx you for answer. How to use this? Please, Could you make an example?

Comment: This hides everything :)

Comment: Sorry dude, you're in over your head.